# Xamarin Forms - How to have TableView and ListView Extend into iPhone X Safe Area?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I use the platform specific use safe area in the page constructors but the tableview and listview are pushed up and don't extend to the bottom of the page. For example, in the attached image, you can see that the tableview grey doesn't extend to the bottom of the page. How can I get it to fill in?

[image: Settings TableView on iOS not extending to bottom of the screen]

Comment: could you fix this issue? I've a list view, where I want it to overlap the home indicator (if it extends the screen), but if I scroll to the end it should account for it and move the last element above the home indicator.

Comment: @SebastianGreifeneder I did fix it but not the way I wanted. I turned off safe area for that page alone and it worked properly. I guess since it was just a listview it knew what to do. This would not work if the page had more views than just a list view. I kept the safe area on for the other pages and those were fine.

Comment: I can confirm the behavior you mention. If the list view is the child of the ContentPage, then it works out-of-the-box and you don't even have to specify a safe area. Doesn't work if the list view is in a layout though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `BackgroundColor` of the page. UseSafeArea only adds padding so whatever the `BackgroundColor` of the ContentPage is will be exposed. if you want it to be your tableview gray, you need to set `ContentPage.BackgroundColor = Color.Gray`.

Comment: This gives a different color grey on the bottom bar. I'm also not a fan of this as what if iOS 13 changes the look of a tableview or iOS dark mode is turned on? It's not extending the view down to the bottom like in iOS where the tableview would be the full screen but the cells would not go down to the bottom but stop above the bar.

Comment: You can set it to whatever color you want. you can use hex to get the exact same shade of gray to match the tableview. As for dark mode, you should be using DynamicResources to account for colors. When the user switches to dark mode, your app should use the appropriate color scheme. If you're referring to iOS 13s system wide dark mode, that isn't automatic in your app. you have to have your app handle that.

Comment: I am referring to iOS 13's system wide dark mode which IS automatic in native apps with tableviews. All my native non xamarin apps automatically change color. They also properly handle the safe area with cell content going past the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

In fact in your case, you **don't** want safe area.

So put `UseSafeArea` to false, and handle the padding yourself.

Comment: This doesn't work for listviews when the amount of cells goes down the screen. On a native Xcode app, using the safe area would account for this.

Answer (score -1):

you can add the below code for iPhone safe area.

```
xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" 
           ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
```